# Difficulties Converting a Standalone to a Replica Set

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I want to use MongoDB River for ElasticSearch, but for this purpose I need to convert my standalone to replica set.

I followed the [official documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) but, I encounter this message when going through Step 2:

```
replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)
```

Some references say I need to run `rs.initiate()`, but how can I do this while the Mongo server is shutdown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a break and read the documentation with calm :) they don't say to just shut down the server, they say to shut down your actual mongo istance (because that one is been started as a standalone instance), and right after to start again that instance with a different string, they give that in example:

> mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/db0 --replSet rs0

where --dbpath point to the path of your datafiles. 
rs0 is the name of the replicaset, choose your one or just use this

then you can run rs.initiate()

BUT: if you already made some try, and you runned an rs.initiate() without succed, you have to do something before repeat all the procedure:

1. start the server in your usual way (single instance)
2. connect to the instance with a similar command : `mongo --port 27017`
3. look at your databases : `show dbs`
4. if there is a db called local, connect to it: `use local`
5. drop that database : `db.dropDatabase()`

then you can repeat all the procedure and try to properly set up your replicaset.

Comment: Thanks mate! I'll take extra care redoing the procedure and I'll give you my feedback!

Comment: I succeeded but how to run the instance permanently because I need to close it to continue with my shell, Can I run it in background ?

Comment: @Sekai control + z sends it to background if your on linux

Comment: I used --fork --syslog instead :) Thanks guys !

Comment: good job glad you did it! you can also open an other terminal and work from there keeping the server instance running in the other terminal

Answer (score 0):

It says clearly on the next 2 steps what needs to be done.

Use `mongo` console to connect to the MongoDB server and then run `rs.initiate()`

Comment: @Vincenzo Hmm, not sure why you would necro a answer nearly 7 years old, but I wold think rs.initiate()( being a command only for the mongo shell it would make sense to need to run the mongo shell, how else would you run it? Not knowing that probably means you wasn't reading properly and just skimming

Comment: Well of course it is obvious to you, but as the answer from lese shows, no so for others. `shut down your actual mongo istance` is at least confusing,while stop the instance would be clearer( I fell into that  too and still struggling with the procedure, that's how I found the the post)..anyways I hope I haven't come across in an offensive way, just meant to brat about the attitude that sam devs have here.. We all have started knowing nothing..but some of us seem to have forgotten those days.. Cheers